# Updating dataframe values with functions at scale

Tags: r

I've got a data frame that requires some manual overrides of certain values given different conditions. But, these conditions tend to take a consistent form (I'm always going to be replacing one value with another, given a specific date range, etc.).

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to do the following; I suspect there is, given that I'm repeating function calls over and over. Here's an example:

```
set.seed(1234); library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(
    biz = sample(c("telco","shipping","tech"), 50, replace = TRUE),
    region = sample(c("mideast","americas","asia"), 50, replace = TRUE),
    date = rep(seq(as.Date("2010-02-01"), length=10, by = "1 day"),5)
    )
```

Now, as described above, I want to change values in this dataframe subject to certain conditions about values of the other variables. My first thought is to use a function:

```
changeFunc <- function(df, ...) {
    df$region <- ifelse(df$date %in% daterange &
        data$biz == string1, string2, as.character(data$region))
    return(df)
}
```

And then to actually update the dataframe, call that function:

```
daterange <- as.Date('2010-02-05') + 0:02; string1 <- 'telco'; string2 <- 'southeast'
data <- changeFunc(data, daterange, string1, string2)
```

The problem is, I want to do this over and over again for different date ranges and values for "string 1" and "string 2", eg:

```
daterange <- as.Date('2010-02-07') + 0:03; string1 <- 'shipping'; string2 <- 'northeast'
data <- changeFunc(data, daterange, string1, string2)

data %.% arrange(biz, region, date)
```

Is there a more automated way to make many changes to dataframe values subject to consistent rules?

**EDIT: Update with a bit more clarity:**
What I ultimately want to do is not have to define 'daterange','string1','string2' and call the function repeatedly. Maybe there's some way to leverage an "apply" function to have a list of pre-defined values for the date ranges and strings and update the dataframe all at once? Something like:

```
valList <- list(daterange = as.Date('2010-02-05') + 0:02, string1 = "telco", string2 = "southeast",
                daterange2 = as.Date('2010-02-07') + 0:03, string1_2 = "shipping", string2_2 = "northeast")
```

And apply this over the dataframe with the changeFunc

But as you can see, I'm a bit unclear about how the function would know that string1_2 is the condition that matches with daterange2 and not daterange

Comment: Not an answer, but make sure you have the latest `dplyr` version (I say that because you are still using `%.%` whereas that was replaced by `%>%` in more recent versions of dplyr)

Comment: It's unclear to me what's the logic you want to use to apply the changes "over and over again for different date ranges and values".. Can you explain that in more detail? Perhaps you could use a function of the apply family to run through a list of values to be changed but as it's currently written, it's not very clear.

Comment: @beginneR, see my update. Using "apply" functions is my best guess but I'm at a loss for how to go about making sure the function reads the conditions correctly, eg, "daterange" relates to string1 and string2, NOT string1_2 and string2_2. Does that help?